# Setup Auth0 with local database ran in a docker container

Tags: javascript, mysql, docker, authentication, localhost

I've got a web-page at localhost:8080 with a login button that triggers a call to the auth0 handler. It works fine as long as it interacts with their database. Now i'm trying to set-up my own database, but can't seem to fill correctly the login script.

My database runs through a docker container via the command-line:

```
docker run —ip="172.0.0.3" —net="unihub-network" -p 13306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypasswd -d unihub-mysql
```

Using their template, I wrote:

```js
function login(email, password, callback) {
  var connection = mysql({
    host: 'my-ip-address',
    user: 'my-user',
    password: 'my-psw',
    database: 'UNIHUB_DB' //supposed to be the name of my db
 });
```

Which obviously doesn't work. I can access my DB through software like SQuirreL at `jdbc:mysql://localhost:13306/UNIHUB_DB`, but it looks like i would need to access it through a URL to put in the login script for auth0.

Any thought on this ?

Comment: What are the variable values you use for the `mysql()` method?

Comment: Reading their doc, ‘host’ has to be accessible from the internet, so I put my own IP address. User and password are the ones I use when connecting to my DB through SQuirreL